# Calculus of residue

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

i try to do the following

```
Assuming[k\[Element] Integers,Residue[Cos[x]/x^(k+1),{x,0}]]
```

but any respond how to calculate for any k
the k derivate of Cos function 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient):

```
res[k_] = Assuming[
    k ∈ Integers && k > 0,
    FullSimplify @ SeriesCoefficient[x^(-1-k) Cos[x], {x, 0, -1}]
]
```

> Cos[(k π)/2]/k!

Check:

```
res[Range[10]]

Table[Residue[x^(-1-k) Cos[x], {x, 0}], {k, 10}]
```

> {0, -(1/2), 0, 1/24, 0, -(1/720), 0, 1/40320, 0, -(1/3628800)}
>
> {0, -(1/2), 0, 1/24, 0, -(1/720), 0, 1/40320, 0, -(1/3628800)}

Comment: Thanks @Carl  this method  i have been used but for Complicate function do not work cause Mathematica could not find the n derivate it is possibel calculate  the other way